# Apollo + React Router 4 SSR issue

Tags: javascript, react-router, apollo

Not sure if this is an issue with React Router v4, the React Apollo client or my implementation.

But with `<ApolloProvider>` as the top-level HOC, i.e:

```
const ComponentsWithData = await getDataFromTree(
  <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
    <StaticRouter location={ctx.request.url} context={route}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>,
  </ApolloProvider>,
);

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(ComponentsWithData);
```

... I get:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `ApolloProvider`, expected a single ReactElement.
>       in ApolloProvider
>   Error React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

And flipped around, with React Router's `<StaticRouter>` as the top, i.e.:

```
const ComponentsWithData = await getDataFromTree(
  <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
    <StaticRouter location={ctx.request.url} context={route}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>,
  </ApolloProvider>,
);
```

... I then get:

> A `<Router>` may have only one child element

Rendering works fine in the browser (with React Router's `<BrowserRouter>`), but fails on the server.

It also works well in React Router v3 due to doing all of the route matching *outside* of the React hierarchy, and not declaratively inside of it.

Answer (score 5):

This was actually a user error. I expected `getDataFromTree()` to return a Promise that resolved to the original component chain (with the correctly injected GraphQL data props), but it actually just waits for the data to be ready.

The correct format is:

```
const Components = (
  <StaticRouter location={ctx.request.url} context={route}>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </StaticRouter>
);

await getDataFromTree(Components);
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Components);
```